# PHP - Extend parent class from child class which is in another directory

Tags: php, class, inheritance

I try to create a parent class for all my "Model" classes.

I have a class in `app/code/core/User/Model/User.php` named `User_Model_User` it should inherit from a parent class in `app/code/core/Core/Model.php`

[image]

**Attempt:**

**Parent:**

```
class Model
{
    public function testParent()
    {
        echo "123";
    }
}
```

**Child:**

```
class User_Model_User extends Core\Model
{
    private $con;
    private $user_id;

    public function __construct($con)
    {
        $this->con = $con;
    }

    public function loadByEmail($email)
    {
        $this->user_id = $this->getUserId($email);
        return $this;
    }
...
```

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Class 'Core\Model' not found in
>   /var/www/property-rights/app/code/core/User/Model/User.php

How does it work?

Comment: Does your class have a namespace? You need to provide a little more example code so we can rule out any issues.

Comment: But does the parent class have a namespace? You cannot extend something purely based on the folder structure. You need the class to have a namespace, that you can then extend from.

Comment: No it doesn't have a namespace.

Comment: Your issue has definitely been related to you not having a namespace on the class. when you extend like `Core\Model`, then you are extending the namespace, but since it did not one, you could not extend from it. Add the namespace, then I'm sure it works.

Comment: @SeverinDK, I already solved it yesterday. Look at my answer please, im not sure if it is the best way though.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but I solved it like this:

**Main:** *app/Main.php*

Put `<project_root>/app/code/core` in include path, so that I don't have to use the full path when calling `include`, `require` etc.

```
if (!defined('DS')) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
if (!defined('PS')) define('PS', PATH_SEPARATOR);
if (!defined('BP')) define('BP', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

Main::register('original_include_path', get_include_path());

$paths = array();
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'core';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'local';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'lib';
$paths[] = BP . DS . 'inc';

$appPath = implode(PS, $paths);
set_include_path($appPath . PS . Main::registry('original_include_path'));
```

**Parent:**

```
namespace Core;

class Model
{
```

**Child:**

```
require_once("Core/Model.php");

class User_Model_User extends Core\Model
{
```